# Ordered values - select first instance of lowest value, then first instance of next lowest subsequent value and so on

Tags: r, dplyr, subsequence

I have a dataframe with with many distinct UniqueIDs, and which are also ordered by dates. Each UniqueID is sorted from oldest date to newest date. We also have a column called steps which is ordered from 1 to 4.

The goal is for each UniqueID is to find the oldest instance of the first Step, then the oldest instance of the second step etc. Some steps may be missing, for instance step 3 is missing for UniqueID  = "B". In this case we skip over Step 3 and move on to step 4.

Here is the original dataframe.

```
   UniqueID       Date Step
1         A 2015-07-03    2
2         A 2015-07-07    3
3         A 2015-07-09    1
4         A 2015-07-14    4
5         A 2015-07-17    1
6         A 2015-07-20    2
7         A 2015-07-23    2
8         A 2015-07-24    3
9         A 2015-07-29    3
10        B 2015-06-01    3
11        B 2015-06-15    2
12        B 2015-06-22    1
13        B 2015-06-29    4
14        B 2015-07-13    2
15        B 2015-06-22    2
16        B 2015-07-08    2
17        B 2015-07-27    4
```

The valid entries we want to select are observations 3, 6, 8, 12, 14, 17. Creating this dataframe:

```
 UniqueID       Date Step
3         A 2015-07-09    1
6         A 2015-07-20    2
8         A 2015-07-24    3
12        B 2015-06-22    1
14        B 2015-07-13    2
17        B 2015-07-27    4
```

I have the logic and some pseudo code but can't put it together. So in the example data frame for UniqueID = "A" we would first group the dataframe:

`group_by(UniqueID)`

The find the lowest value for UniqueID = "A" and assign to a variable.

`v <- min(Step)`returns 1

Then take the index for this step

`i <- which.min(Step)` returns 3

We then want to find the min step that is greater than the first step, and only search the elements that occur after the first step. So now we are only searching for values of Step which are > 1, and only from the position of the first value we found onward, in this case from observation 3. We want to keep repeating this for all observations of each UniqueID until we either reach the last observation, or can no longer find an observation that is greater than the last observation in the remaining elements.

Here is the dput for creating the example dataframe:

```
structure(list(UniqueID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(16619, 16623, 16625, 
16630, 16633, 16636, 16639, 16640, 16645, 16587, 16601, 16608, 
16615, 16629, 16608, 16624, 16643), class = "Date"), Step = c(2, 
3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4)), .Names = c("UniqueID", 
"Date", "Step"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Alternative dput which crashes using jeremycg's method.

```
structure(list(UniqueID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("A","B",
"C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"),
class = "factor"), Date = c("3/08/2015", 
"21/07/2015", "7/07/2015", "7/07/2015", "29/07/2015", "29/07/2015", 
"29/06/2015", "13/07/2015", "9/07/2015", "29/07/2015", "24/07/2015", 
"2/07/2015", "16/07/2015", "18/06/2015", "8/07/2015", "29/07/2015", 
"12/06/2015", "27/07/2015"), Step = c(1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
5, 5, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2)), .Names = c("UniqueID", 
"Date", "Step"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Edit: dput of UniqueID that continues to crash even using updated code from jeremycg :

```
structure(list(UniqueID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L ), .Label = c("A"                                                                                              ), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(16619, 16623, 16625,                                                                                                                                          16630, 16633, 16636), class = "Date"), Step = c(1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("UniqueID",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "Date", "Step"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please explain more? I am not getting how did you manage to get the output data frame. What do you mean by the oldest entries?

Comment: @RonakShah The entries are sorted from oldest to newest by the "Date" column. So to get the first value, we find the minimum value of Step for observations where UniqueID = "A" which is 1. There are actually three observations of 1 for UniqueID equal to "A" but the one we want is the oldest, which is why observation 3 is selected in the output dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty inefficient, but working.

First define a function:

```
myseq <- function(df){
  if(which.min(df$Step) == nrow(df)){
    return(list(df[nrow(df),]))
  }
  store <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df))
  i=1
  while(any(!is.na(df$Step))){
    store[[i]] <-  df[which.min(df$Step),]
    df <- df[which.min(df$Step) : nrow(df), ]
    df$Step[df$Step == min(df$Step)] <- NA
    i = i+1
  }
  store
}
```

Then wrap it on the dataframe using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dta %>% group_by(UniqueID) %>%
        do(do.call(rbind, myseq(.)))
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: UniqueID

  UniqueID       Date Step
1        A 2015-07-09    1
2        A 2015-07-20    2
3        A 2015-07-24    3
4        B 2015-06-22    1
5        B 2015-07-13    2
6        B 2015-07-27    4
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It does work with the test dataframe. But with the real data set it crashes. I have provided the dput for a sample of 18 rows of the real dataset which is crashing, please see my edit to the OP providing the dput for the dataframe that causes this solution to crash.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I've tried it with 5000 rows and it crashes. Would you expect that to occur?

Comment: Hi, I've narrowed the error down to one UniqueID that causes it to crash. I've posted the dput as another edit in the OP. I can't see why it would crash.

Comment: I've done some tests and the problem only seems to occur when the first and last Step number are the same, and there are some other step numbers in between them. So even a sequence of 1, 2, 1 would crash.

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding `na.rm = TRUE` to this line:
`df$Step[df$Step == min(df$Step, na.rm=TRUE)] <- NA1`